# Hapi.js response middleware

Tags: node.js, pipeline, middleware, hapi.js

I would like to “wrap” or manipulate every response from REST API calls.

I want to use a middleware/pipeline, but just in the response flow.

Example:

```
{data: everyResponseReturnVal}
```

I am using hapi.js as server side node.js framework.

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer is kind of late but here's a complete example to achieve what you asked for

```js
const Hapi = require('@hapi/hapi')
const server = Hapi.server({ port: 8000 })

const success = function (data) {
  return this.response({ data })
}

server.decorate('toolkit', 'success', success)

server.route({
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/{name}',
  handler: function (request, h) {
    return h.success(request.params.name)
  }
})
```